# How to do ASP.NET Web API integration tests with custom authentication and in-memory hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, authorization, integration-testing, iprincipal

A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631454/2994422)  but the answer doesn't seem to work in my case.

I want to test the authentication/authorization process in my Web Api which is using a JWT authentication.

My authentication is handled through a custom `MessageHandler` that I add to my `HttpConfiguration`. Authorization in handled by a simple `[Authorize]` Attribute on Controller/Methods I want to restrict access to.

I'm setting the principal I've extracted from my token this way during authentication (in my custom `MessageHandler`):

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
     HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
}
```

This whole process is working fine when I test it manually in a local IIS.

But when testing with an in-memory hosting like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631454/2994422)
The `ApiController.User` property storing the Principal that is used for authorization with `[Authorize]` get the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` in my calling test (the windows principal of my current session) instead of the one set during authentication.
If I set my `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to null, I get only bad requests.

**TL;DR** How do I test my authentication/authorization pipeline with in memory hosting 
? As it sets the `ApiController.User` value to the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` value in my test and not getting the one I set successfully during authentication.

I think I can manage to do a work around with implementing a custom `[Authorize]` Attribute getting the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and not the `ApiController.User`, but I'd like to avoid that.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** for clarification: all this pipeline (authentication then authorization) is working fine hosted in a running IIS (with an HttpContext which is null during in memory hosting). I'm just trying to test it with in memory hosting (if it is possible). During testing with in memory hosting , putting breakpoints in my custom `MessageHandler`, I can tell that the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is well set, it's just that  `[Authorize]` doesn't seem to care about that, as, in my ApiControllers the `ApiController.User` property is already set to the value of my `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` value in my test (my local Windows session principal)

Comment: which version of ASP.NET Web API are you using here? can you post the message handler code which authenticates the requests?

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET Web API 2.1 and [here](https://github.com/jamiekurtz/JwtAuthForWebAPI/blob/master/src/JwtAuthForWebAPI/JwtAuthenticationMessageHandler.cs) you can find a somewhat similar message handler to authenticate the requests (ligne 110 I'm not using a PrincipalTransformer but assigning the principal I get from tokenHandler.ValidateToken straight away)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had success following the guidance listed in the ["Retrieving and Assigning the Current Principal" section of Chapter 15 in "Designing Evolvable Web APIs with ASP.NET"](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/ch15.html#_retrieving_and_assigning_the_current_principal):

> In ASP.NET Web API version 2.0, you can solve this problem by using
>   the new HttpRequestContext class. First, the current identity should
>   be retrieved and assigned to the current request object, not to a
>   static property. Secondly, different hosts can use different
>   HttpRequestContext implementations

In short, in your message handler, do this instead of setting the current Thread and HttpContext's principal:

```
request.GetRequestContext().Principal = principal;
```

Comment: After 2 days of looking for a solution, this worked for me. Thanks.