# Windows Auth with Microsoft.Owin.Testing.TestServer

Tags: authentication, testing, asp.net-web-api, owin, windows-authentication

I have a Web API application which I'm protecting with Windows Authentication (locally, it'll translate to AD in the production environment). I just started adding features that rely on authentication and/or getting properties of the current user, and I immediately fell on a road block: the testing server doesn't seem able to authenticate.

How can I make the following test code send an authenticated request using Windows Authentication?

```
using (var server = Microsoft.Owin.Testing.TestServer.Create(MyApp.Startup.Configure)) {
    var response = server.HttpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
    // Assert things about the response
}
```

Comment: Interesting, do you get the response in your example as if no authentication had ever been implemented?

Comment: @AnishPatel: If I remove the authorization requirement from the action I'm testing, it works as long as I don't try to access the current user (if I do, I get an exception, since there is none...). With the auth requirement, I get a 401 (just as I want for an unauthorized request). What I need, is to be able to authenticate (or mock the authentication of) a Windows user through the testing server.

Comment: I know is late but for future problems, this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24714361/5147720